Blackened Cooker Insulation
I've attached an image of the back of my cooker which shows some blackening of the insulation around the top, is this normal or a problem please?


I will let someone else answer, but the wire insulation looks good/not burnt/melted, so that is a good sign.  The green/ground wire in the centre does not seem to be connected, probably the picture.

In that location, away from electric bits and pieces, most likely due to smoke from food coming out the hole where the thermostat sensor line emerges. Bon appétit!

it's accumulated dust that's blackening, not glass; no problem.
